# Turn off password protected sharing

Tags: batch-file, password-protection, file-sharing

I'm writing a batch file to create a folder and share it in the network. The access to it has to be without authentication. The script has run in windows 7 64 bit.
I use "net share" to share my folder and "CALCS" to modify the access control.
It works properly but I can't disable the password protected sharing.

How can I turn off password protected sharing using a batch file?

Comment: Can you post your batch file please? Your `cacls` should set the permissions so that it doesn't need a password.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, below there are the script's lines interesting my question: 

net share Public=C:\Users\Public /GRANT:Everyone,FULL
CACLS C:\Users\Public /E /G Everyone:F

I'm using elevated rights ;-)